# Is there a way to select what members of one instance I want to assign without manually assigning them all

Tags: c++, class

lets assume I have `Class C` that has members `x,y,z,t,u,v`

```
C c1,c2;
//... 
c1.x = c2.x;
c1.u = c2.u;
c1.v = c2.v;
```

Can this code be condensed so that I can just list `x, u, v`?

EDIT: motivation is that I have a Class that gets updated but some values are not calculated again since they remain the same.

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor?

Comment: You can do some stuff with pointers to member objects, but I don't see it as a big improvement.

Comment: cant you use properties like c# ; check this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx)

Comment: @theghostofc I have CC, but I dont wanna hack it, beside it is still the same amount of code

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes what about taking c2, c2.x, c2.u.c2.v calculating offsets in the class to get members of c1 and then assigning them. You know what you are asigning because it is the same class so you can use decltype and casting on some offset from this...

Comment: "calculating offsets" == getting pointers to members, but losing the type information. Id est, that's more or less the same solution, just a bit more hackish.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, you are right! You may create a member function or overload `= operator`. This is one time code only. Are you using `C++` or `C++.Net`?

Comment: @theghostofc C++11ish (VC2010)

Comment: I'll modify my answer and give a C# example which is quick to implement and works perfectly!

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, did you check my updated answer? Will it work for you?

Comment: @theghostofc no, since we use unmanaged C++. For people using C++ CLI it might be beneficial. still nice solution for CLI

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, I thought so. All the best for your search :)

Answer (score 5):

The code cannot be **condensed** with any reasonable method (i.e. avoiding macros and obscure mechanisms).

However, it can be **encapsulated** in an assignment operator for your class. Overload the "=" operator and put all those assignments in its body. Then you just need to do c1 = c2.

Of course if your semantics are not those of assignment, you can just create a traditional method `AssignSomeFields(const C& other)`. Then just call `c1.AssignSomeFields(c2);`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to condense it onto one line (and you can't overload `operator=`), then you could use `std::tie`, found in `<tuple>` assuming you have C++11.

You could use it like follows:

```
C c1, c2;
...
std::tie( c1.x, c1.u, c1.v ) = std::tie( c2.x, c2.u, c2.v );
```

This doesn't make the code smaller, just puts it on one line, which you may find more convenient.

Comment: `c1.x = c2.x; c1.u = c2.u; c1.v = c2.v;` is one line as well - you won't gain anything by this and only lose readability, since the elements that get assigned to each other are now separated and errors are harder to find.

Answer (score 1):

If C is a *class* with methods and so on, you should make your member variables private and not public. Having said that, the update from `c2` to `c1` has to be implemented as a member function. This member function should be `operator=` **if it really has assignment semantics**, meaning that after the update the two objects are semantically equal.
If it does *not* have assignment semantics, you should use a normal, named member function, where the name should be a good description of what the update means. In that case, you will have to make the memberwise assignment in that update-function:

```
void C::updateSomeParts(C const& other) {
  x = other.x;
  u = other.u;
  v = other.v;
}
```

If you don't want to write x,u and v twice and maybe use the same parts on other occasions you should consider gathering them in a subobject:

```
class C {
  struct SomePart {
    int x;
    double u;
  };

  SomePart sp;
  bool z;

  void updateSomeParts(C const& other) { sp = other.sp; }
};
```

However, you'll now have to explicitly access the members of `sp`, like `sp.u = 5` instead of just `u = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to overload the `=` operator. See: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/

Alternatively, you could define a member function of the class `C` to do the work for you like `c1.copy(c2)`

Answer (score 0):

Have a `copy constructor` or overload the `= operator`.

## Edit:

Sharing a `C#` example which may not really work for you as it requires `.Net Framework` and `public Properties`. But this one is quick and readable.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using ...

class Z
{
    public int x {get; set;}
    public string u {get; set;}
    public string w {get; set;}
    ...
}
class C
{
    public int x {get; set;}
    public string u {get; set;}
    public string v {get; set;}
    ...
}
class Conversion
{
    public void Convert()
    {
        C c1, c2;
        ...
        ...
        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c1);
        c2 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<C>(data);  // copies all public properties from c1 to c2

        Z z1;
        ...
        ...
        data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c1);
        z1 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Z>(data);  // copies value for only matching properties
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

> We may even use templates with this library. We used these to copy model values from one object to another. This may not apply in your case as models have mostly `public properties` which may not be the case here. I have not checked it with `private` or `protected` data members.